# Using react-addons-perf with react native

Tags: performance, reactjs, react-native

I am not able to measure anything using Perf.start/Perf.stop in a react-native app. Perf.getLastMeasurements() always returns an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

I've been running into the same problem.

One thing that (just) worked for me was to import from `ReactPerf` instead of importing from `react-addons-perf`.

So, for example (ES6):

```
import Perf from 'ReactPerf';

...

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...

  componentWillMount() {
    Perf.start();
    setTimeout(() => {
      Perf.stop();
      console.warn('Measurements');
      const measurements = Perf.getLastMeasurements();
      Perf.printInclusive(measurements);
  }, 8000);

  ...
}
```

Hope this helps (I'm not too sure why it works, how the dependencies are set up, or what packages you need to `npm install`, but this somehow worked for me).

Comment: Hey Deon, I'm trying to run your code but I get "getLastMeasurements is not a function". Did anything change? Perf.start and Perf.stop works just fine.

Comment: I dislike Haste dependencies in my code, but I've found this works too (for the moment): import Perf from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/ReactPerf';